# Rails and jQuery: saving states in sessions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery

I'm trying to save the state of a jQuery toggle in a Rails app with little success. How would I store it in a session? Or would I store it in a cookie? Thanks for your help.

Here's the jQuery that handles the toggle:

```
$(function() {
  function showHideDocuments() {
    $("#accordion").toggle("blind", 500);
  };
  $("#finalised-documents").click(function() {
    showHideDocuments();
    return false;
  });
});
```

I don't really know how to proceed from here. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone else struggling with this, here's a solution. Use the jQuery cookie plugin with this code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#finalised-documents').click(function () {
if ($('#accordion').is(':hidden')) {
  $('#accordion').slideDown(500);
  $.cookie('forgetmenow', 'showing');
} else if ($('#accordion').is(':visible')) {
  $('#accordion').slideUp(500);
      $.cookie('forgetmenow', 'hidden');
    }
  });   
  if($.cookie('forgetmenow') == 'hidden') {
    $('#accordion').hide();
  };
});
```

Enjoy.